# Editing tags in a question if tag needs more reputation?

Tags: support

Let's say I'm editing a question of a user with 200.000k reputation. Probably he can tag some specific tags that needs more reputation. For example if I want to put 'hey' tag in my question it says

> Creating the new tag 'hey' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try
>   something from the existing tags list instead.

So I can't do that now. But a user with high rep can do this, If I edit that question, can I put a tag like `hey` since I don't have enough rep but he has?

Same question to backwards, if a high rep user editing a question and want to put a tag that needs 1500rep but OP's rep is lower than that, can he do that? Since editer has the enough rep but OP not.

Comment: @nkjt How that question/answer has an answer to mine?

Comment: Doesn't the first paragraph of the answer there answer your question?   *Any user with at least 1500 reputation may add new tags to any question*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The person *making the edit* needs to have the 1,500 reputation to create the tag. The person who asked the question is not relevant to the process.

Comment: Alright, what about backwards? Editer has enough rep but OP not

Comment: It's the same backwards. The person who asked the question is not relevant, ever.

Comment: But then editer can put a specific tag in to that question? If OP is not relevant, then editer can put a specific tag if his rep is enough, right?

Comment: Yes, if you have 1,500 reputation, you can create a tag. On any question. Regardless of who asked the question.